# Lowering the minSDKVersion

Tags: android, sdk

I bymistakely made an app using sdk version 22+
and i have published that app to the play store,

So what will happen if i change the minSDKVersion from 22 to 17 in the gradle file ? i want to support people using those android versions too. A big mistake. how can i do this ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.femindharamshi.spa"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.github.kbiakov:CodeView-android:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The new version will support the lower versions.  So long as you keep it changed, you'll be fine.  Although given the usage stats at https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/ I wouldn't really spend a lot of time supporting them, especially if you have a western audience (which skews higher)

Comment: No actually the audience is INDIAN and many of them i have noticed use a lower android version, so should i directly reduce the minSDK thingy ?

Comment: Yes just lower or and upload the new version. After testing to make sure you aren't using any apis added since then, or course